# Ansible Replace module using regex when given item list not working

Tags: regex, replace, automation, ansible, devops

Im trying to find and replace a line in file , tried with  [lineinfile](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html) and [replace](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/replace_module.html) modules

```
- name : Update root-context.xml db details
  replace:
    path: "{{ path_root_context }}"
    regexp: "{{ item.regexp }} "
    replace: "{{ item.line }} "
#    regexp: <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://([a-zA-Z]+):3306/([a-zA-Z]+)\?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;autoReconnect=true"/>
#    replace: <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://"{{ db_url }}":3306/"{{ db_name }}"?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;autoReconnect=true"/>
  with_items:
    - { regexp: '<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://([a-zA-Z]+):3306/([a-zA-Z]+)\?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;autoReconnect=true"/>' , line: '<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://"{{ db_url }}":3306/"{{ name_db }}"?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;autoReconnect=true"/>'}

  become: yes
  become_user: "{{ app_user }}"
```

with commented lines regexp: replace: its working

But when passing it in item list its not working

Can someone help . I will have to use item_list when i have multiple lines to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your task definition is that you have a trailing white space in your regex, `"{{ item.regexp }} "`. Remove that and it should work just fine. Also noted that your replace value has `"` around your `db_name` and `db_url`. An updated version might look like this.

```
- name : Update root-context.xml db details
  replace:
    path: "{{ path_root_context }}"
    regexp: "{{ item.regexp }}"
    replace: "{{ item.line }}"
  with_items:
    - regexp: '<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://([a-zA-Z]+):3306/([a-zA-Z]+)\?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;autoReconnect=true"/>'
      line: '<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://{{ db_url }}:3306/{{ db_name }}?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;autoReconnect=true"/>'
```

Alternatively, for what you are doing, you might want to consider the [xml module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/xml_module.html). Here is an example task, you might need to update the xpath query depending on your xml file.

```
- name: Update root-context.xml db details
  xml:
    path: "{{ path_root_context }}"
    xpath: /Context/property[@name='url']
    attribute: value
    value: "jdbc:mysql://{{ db_url }}:3306/{{ db_name }}?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;autoReconnect=true"
```

Comment: Thank you so much . It worked . However the xml module failed with error code 
'fatal: [demoapp1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "The xml ansible module requires the lxml python library installed on the managed machine"}'